# Where (in memory) does Linux kernel store 'special' bus addresses?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

When the kernel starts, it has to find hardware and get ready to run programs. Kernel 'looks' at I/O ports — special bus addresses that are likely to have device controller cards. The kernel doesn't poke at random; it has a lot of built-in knowledge about what it's likely to find where, and how controllers will respond if they're present. Source: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Unix-and-Internet-Fundamentals-HOWTO/bootup.html

Are those special bus addresses stored in kernel space?

Thank you!

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you mean by "addresses stored in kernel space". Do you mean "mapped to the kernel space"?

Comment: Yes, I mean mapped to the kernel space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are stored in kernel space memory. There is a kernel function called `request_region` which a driver can use to "register" the range of I/O ports which it intends to use. The kernel keeps those registered I/O port "regions" in a tree-like structure, which (of course) resides in kernel memory. Individual drivers also keep track of the I/O ports which they are using in their own memory, which is kernel-space memory.